# Windows 7 - Always use hover color in taskbar when window is active (like Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Is there a way to use the hover color whenever my app is open -- like on Ubuntu? (The rightmost is what I want whenever chrome is open)

[image: From this] [image: to this]

Would make it significantly easier to see which window/application is currently active + the color effect is quite nice in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not easy to do, but you can use a UxTheme [patcher](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/28377-theme-how-apply-custom-themes.html) or [service](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/34579-enabling-custom-themes-windows-7-a.html), edit the appropriate image resources (see below) in the default aero.msstyles and apply your custom theme.

   [image: 1]

   See [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/266336-taskbar-button-change-color-orange-flashing-button.html) for a detailed tutorial.
2. If doing it yourself is not your cup of tea, someone's already done it for you [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/themes-styles/123841-solved-active-inactive-windows-too-similar-aero.html) (read all instructions carefully).

   [image: 2]
3. You can also use an app such as [TaskBowFree](http://www.taskbow.com):

   > TaskBowFree is a taskbar replacement for Windows 2000, Window XP and Windows 7. TaskBowFree can paint programs on the taskbar, and it's convenient: you can find programs that you are looking for faster, because the human eyes have a good response to different colors.
   >
   > TaskBowFree is taskbar with colored buttons, which you can reorder and paint as you wish by mouse easily.

   [image: 3]

   > **Assignments**
   >
   > TaskBowFree can assign colors to programs. By default, when you first start TaskBowFree, it has several appointments colors for applications that are commonly used: MS Notepad, MS Word, MS Excel, MS Outlook. In addition, Taskbow contains "pink" coloring all the windows with the word "media" in the title. So, if you run the MS Media Player or Explorer open the folder "C:\Media\", a program in the taskbar will be pink. Also, you can assign color to program name.

   [image: 4]